# What make road bike is this vintage 1980s bike?

Tags: road-bike, vintage

The headbadge says "WORLD Japan" over a globe. Belleri handlebars, Shimano 600 frame. Lapize on pedal. Seat selle royal.
[image]

[image: WORLD badge]

Comment: Please add a picture of the head-tube badge. I couldn't find anything in [Velobase's database](http://velobase.com/ListHeadBadges.aspx) that was Japanese and matched your description of it.

Comment: So, probably 'WORLD Japan', that's what the badge says.

Comment: @carel Even https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Japanese_bicycle_brands_and_manufacturers doesn't list World as a brand.  Might be something more to this....

Comment: I agree that World doesn't seem to be a brand. Hence, the mystery.

Comment: I'm guessing this is an American company, who maybe had their stuff built in Japan? I doubt a Japanese company would use a view of the world that doesn't include Japan!

Comment: Great point!! Thank you both, much, for looking into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The head tube logo is a match for the one on a Schwinn World Voyager
[image]
on [this bike for sale on ebay](https://www.ebay.com/p/1973-Schwinn-World-Voyageur-Bicycle-Made-in-Japan/1671044876)
However, the parts are not an exact match. 
The parts and chrome are a better match for this 1980s Schwinn World Voyager
[image: 1980s Schwinn World Voyager]
But, you have what looks like a high flange front hub and the Voyager is low flange front and rear. It's been a few year so maybe wheels were changed?
[Here is a history of the Schwinn Voyageur](https://bikehistory.org/bikes/voyageur/)
Looks like the bike came with bar end shifters from 1975 to 1980. In '80 they switched to down tube shifters. Full chrome is available in 1980 and 1981

[According to the wiki article on Schwinn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinn_Bicycle_Company) they were made by Panasonic

> Schwinn soon had a range of low, mid- and upper-level bicycles all imported from Japan. Schwinn's standard road bike model from Panasonic was the World Traveler, which had a high-quality lugged steel frame and Shimano components. Schwinn also marketed a top-shelf touring model from Panasonic, the World Voyager, lugged with butted Tange chrome-molybdenum alloy tubing, Shimano derailleurs, and SunTour bar-end shifters, a serious challenge to the Paramount series at half the price

Comment: [Who called it](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/60211/what-make-road-bike-is-this-vintage-1980s-bike#comment134714_60211) as American-but-built-in-Japan? 

Comment: Thank you, David D. The bike must be a Schwinn. The "parts" (Italian seat, for instance) are worth more than the bike, at this point.

Comment: Yes, David R.--you were right!!

Comment: Vintage Girl - It's a nice bike. They rode well and had OK components. I'm not sure the seat is worth more than the bike.

Comment: In the late 80s, I rode Panasonic's Sport 500 & Sport 1000. They were well-built, quality bikes, and I utilized them for commuting, fitness, and touring Midwestern USA states. Once completed a Century (103 miles) in under 6 hours on the 1000.